# How to set errorChannel when i user a taskExecutor of publishSubscribeChannel?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl

I used publishSubscribeChannel and add a taskExecutor to implement async.

Below is the code.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("mainFlow")
            ..
            .publishSubscribeChannel(subFlowTaskExecutor, subscribe->{
                subscribe.subscribe(flow->
                        flow.channel("testFlow")); })
            ..
            .enrichHeaders(c->c.header(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE,HttpStatus.OK))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow testFlow (){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("testFlow")
            .handler(handlerSomeThing())
            .get();
}
```

As you see ,  mainFlow to testFlow.
Now I want to implement an errorChannel to handle testFlow exception.
So what's the good way to do ?

I tried to use the way like this , implement an ErrorHandler and set into subscribe.But is there any other way ?

```
private TestErrorHandler errorHandler;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("mainFlow")
            ..
            .publishSubscribeChannel(subFlowTaskExecutor, subscribe->{
                subscribe.errorHandler(errorHandler);
                subscribe.subscribe(flow->
                        flow.channel("testFlow")); })
            ..
            .enrichHeaders(c->c.header(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE,HttpStatus.OK))
            .get();
}
```

@Component

public class TestErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

```
@Autowired
private MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(RTSChannel.PerformNameScreening.ERROR_CHANNEL)
private MessageChannel errorChannel;

@Override
public void handleError(Throwable throwable) {
    messagingTemplate.send(errorChannel,new ErrorMessage(throwable));
}

@Bean
public MessagingTemplate errorMessagingTemplate(){
    return new MessagingTemplate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("mainFlow")
```

You can't have a flow with the same name as the first channel in the flow. Assuming you meant

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("mainFlowChannel")
```

Normally, the error channel would be on some component upstream of `mainFlowChannel`.

If you want to scope the error handling just within the subflow, you would need to use a `.gateway()` there.

```java
            .publishSubscribeChannel(subFlowTaskExecutor, subscribe-> flow->
                        flow.gateway(testFlow(), g -> g.errorChannel("errorFlowInputChannel)))
```